# During insertion of the field in the drupal view, there is image contained text but text is displaying not in image

Tags: views

During insertion of the New field in the Drupal view, there is content type field containing text and image but text is displaying not in image what to do ?

**for example**

Filed Name : text_field

[image]

During insertion of the that text_field in the Drupal view the new image not visible what to do? i wanted to display that new image also.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean text and image ? Are they two different fields in content type or single text field with html content which displays image ?

Comment: single text field  html content with image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be field settings issue.. Make sure your field has "full_html" format also,

Make sure formatter is default in view field settings..

[image]

Make sure Rewriting results has not been enabled..

[image]

Comment: ya i selected default but image not displaying only text content is displaying what to do??

Comment: Did you check rewrite results settings ? Are you sure your content has image in html which is getting displayed in View ?

Comment: that new image (Yellow color which i attached the question block) not displaying

Comment: yes yes my content in full html

Comment: Where is the image there ? It's just a text ... Are you talking about word "New" ?

Comment: What was the issue ?

Comment: i am not given full html. i given only filtered html. because of that not displaying. thank you very much